# OOP design problem with Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I have part of the system that looks like this:

[image]

Basically, the client decides which API call to invoke on the server based on the flag that is previously provided. It knows in advance which type of response to expect as well. So the code would look something like this:

```
if (flagOn) {
   Response1 = ApiCall1();
   Process1(Response1);
} else {
   Response2 = ApiCall2();
   Process2(Response2);
}
```

I'm not quite happy with the way this works, first of all because the flag that decides which API to call doesn't belong in the client, but it should be part of the server. `Client` shouldn't know anything about which API's are called in the background, it should just forward the request to server which decides about those things. So, I have started drafting improved version and came up with this:

[image]

In this version, `Client` is only concerned with forwarding the request to the `Server`, where the flow is decided. However, with this design, there is a main issue that needs to be addressed: response type of `ProcessRequest()`. So because `ProcessRequest()` can call either API, and get from them two completely different responses, I'm not able to represent both kind of responses with the same datatype. I wouldn't know what kind of data structure to use on the client in order to represent the response from `ProcessRequest()`. Can anyone help me with this design problem, or maybe suggest an alternative design/solution ?

```
??? response = server.processRequest();
```

  1.

Comment: The client has to know which API call to make as that makes a difference in the returned result. Since `Process1()` method call depends on `flagOn` being true, it makes sense that the client also knows it has to call `ApiCall1()` on the server.

Comment: I get it, but it makes it really impractical to maintain the same config value in two different apps.

Comment: Potentially you can include some type information in your response, which the client can then switch on.  i.e. `{ "responsetype","1" }`

Comment: This feels a little like an XY problem.  You have completely different outputs of 2 APIs but you want to treat them as interchangeable.  I think the design issue is deeper than this particular problem.

Comment: If the two API are completely different in output: why are you switching between them on a flag?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Because they are both valid operations, it's just that the second one is also async, so it won't return the correct data immediately.

Comment: What do you guys think about turning processRequest() into an async operation? Basically, I'm thinking about providing url endpoints as arguments to processRequest(), and processRequest, would know which callback(endpoint) to call after the operation finishes.

Comment: So the results of these two operations are the same, it's just that one responds immediately?  Correct?

Comment: The question then becomes: why not always use the async version?

Comment: it makes sense not to do this within the server because there will be a different client wanting the sync version and your client wanting async..

Answer (score 1):

if client is a component (class, multiple classes) then IMO you should move decision out of the client and the server, and create two separate clients, or one client with two methods. Don't pass flag in to the client, just call specific client or specific method on client:

[image]

or

[image]

EDIT:

If I understund correctly you want to have one generic code to call any external api and to process its response. If that is the case, then you can use generics:

```csharp
public class SomeService {

    public SommeService(ApiClient apiClient, ResponseProccessor responseProcessor) {
        _apiClient = apiClient;
        _responseProcessor = responseProcessor;
    }

    public TResponse CallApi<TRequest,TResponse>(TRequest request){
        var respose = _apiClient.Call<TRequest>(request);
        _responseProcessor.Process<TResponse>(response);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is as Winston Ewert noted in the comments, just always use the asynchronous approach.  With standard `POST` semantics, you `POST` to a URI which will create a sub-resource of that URI.  The `POST` response contains the location of that URI.

You can still do this switch internally if it makes sense.  The client API will be consistent and the client will always `POST` and then do a `GET` on the returned URI.  The difference will be whether the resource will be there before the client is sent the response or if it will be there sometime later.  In order for the client to be agnostic of the details, it should only know that it will be available at the sub-resource location at some point after the call is made, possibly right away.

It's not totally clear from your question that the client even needs the response.  If it's only responsibility is to get the request to the server then this seems like a really good fit for what you want to do.